# Check if sentence contains a phrase

Tags: javascript, search, indexof

**Sentences:**

1. Hey checkout Hello World     <- SHOULD BE INCLUDED
2. hello world is nice!         <- SHOULD BE INCLUDED
3. Hhello World should not work <- SHOULD NOT BE INCLUDED
4. This too Hhhello World       <- SHOULD NOT BE INCLUDED

`var phraseToSearch = "Hello World";`

**Do note:** `sentence.ToLower().IndexOf(phraseToSearch.ToLower())` would not work as it would include all the above sentences while the result should only include sentences 1 and 2

Comment: `/\bhello\sworld\b/gi`

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression to match a character pattern with a string.

The regular expression is simply looking for `Hello World` the exact letters you are looking for with `\b` a word border and using the `i` case insensitive modifier.

Regex has a method `test` that will run the regular expression on the given string. It will return a true if the regular expression matched.

```js
const phraseToSearch = /\bhello world\b/i

const str1 = 'Hey checkout Hello World'
const str2 = 'hello world is nice!'
const str3 = 'Hhello World should not work'
const str4 = 'This too Hhhello World'

console.log(
  phraseToSearch.test(str1),
  phraseToSearch.test(str2), 
  phraseToSearch.test(str3), 
  phraseToSearch.test(str4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a regular expression. Here are the things you want to match

- `Text` (with spaces surrounding it)
- `... Text` (with space on one side, and end of text on the other)
- `Text ...` (with space on one side, and start of side on the other)
- `Text` (just the string, on its own)

One way to do it, without a regular expression, is just to put 4 conditions (one for each bullet point above) and join them up with a `&&`, but that would lead to messy code.

Another option is to split both strings be spaces, and checking if one array was a subarray of another.

However, my solution uses a regular expression - which is a pattern you can test on a string.

Our pattern should

- Look for a space/start of string
- Check for the string
- Look for a space/end of string

`\b`, according to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), will match spaces, seperators of words, and ends of strings. These things are called word boundries.

Here is the code:

```
function doesContain(str, query){ // is query in str
    return new RegExp("\b" + query + "\b", "i").test(str)
}
```

The `i` makes the match case insensitive.